# How to improve Postgresql 'truncate' performance?

Tags: linux, performance, postgresql, truncate, ext4

I am having a problem with truncating all tables in the database on my local machine running Ubuntu 10.09 and Postgresql 9.0 on ext4 fs.

Truncating empty database with 56 tables require about 7 seconds while all my coworkers have a performance about 1 second.

I am truncating all tables with one command. Tables is fully covered with foreign keys.

Does any one know this issue?

Comment: How do you truncate the DB - table by table or all tables in one command? How often your tables have foreign keys?

Comment: Do your coworkers and you use exactly the same database?

Comment: Are you using TRUNCATE TABLE command or running a DELETE statement? Do you have any active queries running against these tables you are running TRUNCATE on?

Comment: My coworkers have the same database created from same dump with foreign keys. Database is empty. No queries running in parallel.

Comment: Are you all using the same version of Ubuntu, the same version of PostgreSQL, and the same kind of filesystem?

Comment: It could be that your system catalogs have gotten bloated from lots of create / drop type stuff.  If you dump / re-init / reload your db it'll probably be snappier again.  More aggressive autovaccum may be required in the future.  It's also possible they're running on drives / file systems that lie about fsync and you are not.

Comment: Just so you know, there were some improvements to `TRUNCATE` performance in 9.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing than your co-workers have write cache enabled on their disks or `fsync` disabled in Postgres configuration.

Comment: Or wrapped in a transaction. 56 tables in 7 seconds ~= 8 fsync's per second if outside of a single transaction, which seems believable for a dying hard drive (or one that's very busy).

Comment: Thanks! Turning `fsync` off improved `truncate` performance on my dev machine 8 times!

Comment: @907th But don't try to run production database with `fsync=off` - you will loose your data sooner or later!